# How to use OpenCV in Numba on Jetson Xavier?

Tags: python, opencv, numba, nvidia-jetson

I'm trying to use OpenCV in some function which I annotate with some Numba decorators (e.g. `nopython=True, parallel=True`). I run this on Jetson Xavier which was flashed with [Nvidia SDK Manager](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetpack).

Code is this:

```python
@jit(nopython=True, cache=True, parallel=True)
def decompress(data):
  result = list()
  for d in data:
    cv2_image = cv2.imdecode(d, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    image = np.array(cv2_image)
    result.append(image)
 return result
```

But I get an error:

```sh
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'resize' of type Module(<module 'cv2' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so'>)

File "./my-script.py", line 297:
            def decompress(data):
                <source elided>
                    cv2_image = cv2.imdecode(d, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
                    ^

[1] During: typing of get attribute at /ssd/catkin_workspace/src/semantics-ros-wrapper/src/semseg.py (297)

File "./my-script.py", line 297:
            def decompress(data):
                <source elided>
                    cv2_image = cv2.imdecode(d, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
                    ^

This is not usually a problem with Numba itself but instead often caused by
the use of unsupported features or an issue in resolving types.

To see Python/NumPy features supported by the latest release of Numba visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html
and
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html

For more information about typing errors and how to debug them visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/troubleshoot.html#my-code-doesn-t-compile

If you think your code should work with Numba, please report the error message
and traceback, along with a minimal reproducer at:
https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/new
```

Is it even possible to use OpenCV with Numba?

I'm using: python2.7 and numba-0.44.0.

Comment: No, I don't think Numba, as of yet (0.46), supports OpenCV.

Answer (score 5):

Numba does not support OpenCV yet.
If you still want it to run on the numpy arrays in your functions you could set `nopython=False`

This means you will also not be able to set `parallel=True`

This is from the [Numba User Manual](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html#nopython):

> Numba has two compilation modes: nopython mode and object mode. The former produces much faster code, but has limitations that can force Numba to fall back to the latter. ***To prevent Numba from falling back, and instead raise an error, pass nopython=True.***